# Relation between Short Wavelength Physics and Long Distance Physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I've heard many times an equivalence of long distance physics with long wavelength/low momentum/low energy physics. However, why is this the case? I believe the argument has to do with the fact that $p$ plays the role of the Fourier dual of $x$, but I was hoping to see an explanation that is more concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $p$ plays the role of the Fourier dual of $x$ is essentially the reason. A rough argument goes as follows.

Consider a wave-function, say of some particle, in momentum space $\widetilde \psi(p)$. Then the position space wave-function reads (up to some conventional normalization factor)
$$
\psi(x) = \int d^dp ~ e^{ip \cdot x} \widetilde \psi(p).
$$
Recall that $|\widetilde \psi(p)|^2$ is the probability distribution of measuring the particle with momentum $p$. Now if $\widetilde \psi(p)$ has support in a region of large $p$, i.e. the particle has a very large momentum, the integral will be dominated by small $x$. This is because if $x$ is not small the exponential is rapidly oscillating and hence a strong cancellation occurs (this is for example the justification for the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation). Thus $\psi(x)$ is supported in a small region around $x = 0$, i.e. everything is restricted to small distances.
On the other hand if $\widetilde\psi(p)$ is supported in a small region around $p = 0$, there is no suppression for larger $x$ so there are sizeable contributions from long distances.